# php isset shorthand else return array not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, isset, shorthand

I have this php code line

```
$data['viewData']['filter'] = isset($parameters['filter']) ? $parameters['filter'] : array('filter1', 'filter2', 'filter3', 'filter4');
```

Is something wrong with the isset shorthand because when I `print_r($data['viewData']['filter']` with else being active, returns nothing/null/empty.

What could be wrong?

Edit, to add more info:

Code inside the controller:

```
if (isset($parameters['filter']))
{
    $data['viewData']['filter'] = $parameters['filter'];
}
else
{
    $data['viewData']['filter'] = array('filter1', 'filter2', 'filter3', 'filter4');              
}
$data['viewData']['query']   = $parameters['search'];
$data['viewData']['results'] = $searchResults;
$data['view'] = 'searchResults';
$this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
```

Code inside view:

```
prePrint($viewData['apis']);
```

And I get nothing when the else enters

Codeigniter is used as framework
*`prePrint` is just a custom function that contains `<pre>` and `print_r();`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. Are you sure the variable is not being influenced by anything else?

Comment: not at all, it's weird because if the isset is true returns the data that is supposed to return but if not, returns nothing

Comment: Are you sure it's hitting the else condition?  Try putting it in an if/else block and do some debug output to confirm $parameters['filter'] really isn't set when you think it isn't...

Comment: Well I have copied your snippet and tested it and it works without problems for me. The reason for the failure must be in another part of your code.

Comment: The code inside the view is returning the empty value? Is `$viewData['apis']` set? You are omitting your view definition. I am confused because nowhere in your code you set a field called 'api' yet you try to read it in your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand what you mean by it returns "nothing/null/empty" since a variable cannot return all 3 of those at once.
isset doesn't check to see if any data exists, it only checks to see if the variable or array index is set. If you want to both make sure it’s set and not empty, try this:

```
if (!empty($parameters['filter']))
```

Comment: :D it's not nothing, null, empty... I meant that it just doesn't return data. And thank you for the solution, that's what I was missing **make sure it's set and also contains data**

Comment: `!empty()` does the same thing as this answer.

Comment: Wow, this was soo long ago! I can’t believe I suggested that as the answer *facepalm*. It does work though.